# How to make BackURL work when resetting password in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I tried using `BackURL` parameter as what is in the link but it does not redirect to `go-here`

```
<domain>/Security/changepassword?m=41&t=4d31275546aff1e16413a2021980b9721e375c15cde307f52f9a1a4f867fb6aaa519acd39cae373711fefc0b2984b1fc2d2e615e2b862e48fe25bbf15db48e3c&BackURL=/go-here.
```

Comment: Please, format your question [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This does not look to be as simple as you have requested because the logic within `ChangePasswordHandler.php` is not using that when the `ChangePasswordForm` is submitted.  I would not advise changing how the security works in this area.